# Spring Boot AuthenticationFilterConfiguration.onStartup is not called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthenticationFilterConfiguration extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationFilterConfiguration.class);

    public AuthenticationFilterConfiguration(){
        LOGGER.info("Setting up authentication filter");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext context) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(context);
        LOGGER.info("Authentication filter configured");
    }

}
```

This is in the same package as the main application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

In my log - I see:

> > 2018-04-10 AuthenticationFilterConfiguration  : Setting up authentication filter

However, I never see the log message from the `onStartup(...)` method that says `Authentication filter configured`.  My other `@Configuration` classes are being loaded (they have lots of `@Bean`s that they create)

Why is the onStartup method not being called?  Everything else works, my RESTful endpoints are working, etc...

Comment: May be this one helps : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/522

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I needed to implement `ServletContextInitializer` instead of the Spring Boot class.  This works just fine:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthenticationFilterConfiguration implements ServletContextInitializer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationFilterConfiguration.class);

    public AuthenticationFilterConfiguration(){
        LOGGER.info("Setting up authentication filter");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext context) throws ServletException {
        LOGGER.info("Authentication filter configured");
    }

}
```